# How to jsDoc node module.exports object methods in Intellij?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, jsdoc, commonjs

I'm trying to get intellij to recognize my jsdocs for an module.exports object. It keeps giving me an `Inferred Type: Function` for the `Crtl + Q` document preview.

Edit: Tried adding `@name module.exports.nameToUpperCase` suggestion from @dez

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Uppercases supplied name.
 * @name module.exports.nameToUpperCase
 * @param name {string} The name to uppercase
 * @returns {string} Uppercase version of the supplied name
 */
var nameToUpperCase = function (name) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
};

module.exports = {
    nameToUpperCase: nameToUpperCase
};
```

I also checked out the jsdocs, but it seems that the only example is to do:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Uppercases supplied name.
 * @param name {string} The name to uppercase
 * @returns {string} Uppercase version of the supplied name
 */
module.exports.nameToUpperCase = function (name) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
};
```

However I am trying to have it appear as the first method since my exports object has many methods.

Comment: Have you tried adding '@name module.exports.nameToUpperCase' in your first example?

Comment: Just tried it, no avail, unless i have it in the wrong spot. I updated my question with what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I send in a ticket to intellij yesterday, same day I made the question post. Today they replied with that I should download the idea 15, currently in beta, as they added in the feature to my request... I tried it, and it works... Wicked fast response and feature built. Intellij ftw.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Uppercases supplied name.
 * @name module.exports.nameToUpperCase
 * @param name {string} The name to uppercase
 * @returns {string} Uppercase version of the supplied name
 */
var nameToUpperCase = function (name) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
};

module.exports = {
    nameToUpperCase: nameToUpperCase
};
```

Now works as expected!